# This powershell runs but why is it so slow

Tags: web-part, powershell, solution-package, web

I ran this powershell which automates wsp addition, activate, deploy web parts and it runs fine. However, it takes about 3 minutes to go through the whole process. Is this norm?

= = = powershell code = = =

```
$retractingPackage=""

function FindInstallationType([string] $WSPName, [string] $VersionNo) 
{                   
    $Tokens = [regex]::Split($WSPName, "\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}")
    #Note: script assumes that the base package name is always unique
    $BasePackageName = $Tokens[0]

    $WSP = Get-SPSolution | where {  
        ($_.Name -match $BasePackageName)
    }  


    if ($WSP -match "\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}") {             

        #store the analyzing package name for future reference
        $global:retractingPackage = $WSP.Name

        $VC0 =  New-Object System.Version($matches[0])
        $VC1 =  New-Object System.Version($VersionNo)

        Write-Host 'Package version in the solution store:' $VC0
        Write-Host 'Package version to be deployed:' $VC1

        return $VC1.CompareTo($VC0)
    }

    # Fresh install
    return [Int]2  

} 

function WaitForJobToFinish([string]$SolutionFileName)
{ 
    $JobName = "*solution-deployment*$SolutionFileName*"    
    $job = Get-SPTimerJob | ?{ $_.Name -like $JobName }
    $maxwait = 30
    $currentwait =0

    if ($job -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host -f Red 'Timer job not found'
    }
    else
    {
        $JobFullName = $job.Name
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Waiting to finish job $JobFullName"        
        while (($currentwait -lt $maxwait)) 
        {
            Write-Host -f Green -NoNewLine .
            $currentwait = $currentwait + 1
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
            if ((Get-SPTimerJob $JobFullName) -eq $null){
            break;
            }
        }
        Write-Host  -f Green "....Done!"
    }
}

function DeployWspPackage([string]$SolutionPath,[string]$SolutionName)
{ 
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "Adding solution:" $SolutionName
    Add-SPSolution $SolutionPath
    Write-Host  -f Green "....Done!"

    Write-Host -NoNewLine "Does the solution contain any web application-specific resources to deploy?"
    $WSP = Get-SPSolution | where {  
        ($_.Name -match $SolutionName)
    }
    if($WSP.ContainsWebApplicationResource)
    {
        Write-Host  -f Yellow "....Yes!"        
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Installing the solution for all web applications:" $SolutionName 
        Install-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionName -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment

    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host  -f Yellow "....No!"     
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Globally deploying the solution:" $SolutionName  
        Install-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionName -GACDeployment
    }
    Write-Host -f Green "....Done!"

    #Waiting for job to finish
    WaitForJobToFinish 

    if ($SolutionName -match "kwizcom sharepoint foundation")
    {
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Installing in central administration site:" $SolutionName        

        $caID = Get-spwebapplication -includecentraladministration | where {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint Central Administration v4"}
        Install-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionName -WebApplication $caID -Force  -GACDeployment

        Write-Host -f Green "....Done!"
    }
}

function RetractWspPackage([string]$SolutionName)
{ 
    Write-Host 'Uninstalling solution:' $SolutionName   
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "Does the solution contain any web application-specific resources to deploy?"
    $WSP = Get-SPSolution | where {  
        ($_.Name -match $SolutionName)
    }
    if($WSP.ContainsWebApplicationResource)
    {
        Write-Host  -f Yellow "....Yes!"        
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Uninstalling the solution from all web applications:" $SolutionName          
        Uninstall-SPSolution -identity $SolutionName  -allwebapplications -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host -f Green "....Done!"


    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host  -f Yellow  "....No!"        
        Uninstall-SPSolution -identity $SolutionName  -Confirm:$false   
        Write-Host -f Green "....Done!"
    }

    #Waiting for job to finish
    WaitForJobToFinish 

    if ($SolutionName -match "kwizcom sharepoint foundation")
    {
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Uninstalling from central administration site:" $SolutionName        

        $caID = Get-spwebapplication -includecentraladministration | where {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint Central Administration v4"}
        Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionName -WebApplication $caID -Confirm:$false

        Write-Host -f Green "....Done!"
    }

    #Waiting for job to finish
    WaitForJobToFinish 

    Write-Host -NoNewLine  'Removing solution:' $SolutionName
    Remove-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionName -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host -f Green "....Done!"
}

function DoDowngradeYesOrNo
    {
    param([string]$title="Confirm",[string]$message="Are you sure you want to downgrade?")
    $choiceYes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Answer Yes."
    $choiceNo = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Answer No."
    $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($choiceYes, $choiceNo)
    $result = $Host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
    switch ($result)
    {
        0 
        {
        return $true
        }

        1 
        {
        return $false
        }
    }
    } 


# Check to ensure Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is loaded
 $snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
 if ($snapin -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
 }

Write-Host 'Retreiving just *.wsp files'
$wspFiles=Get-ChildItem . *.wsp|where-object {!($_.psiscontainer)}

foreach($wspFile in $wspFiles){ 

    if ($wspFile.name -match "\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}" ){

        $solutionName = $wspFile.Name
        $solutionPath = $wspFile.FullName

        # Header 
        Write-Host '---------------------------------'
        Write-Host ''
        Write-Host 'Analyzing package:' $solutionName 
        Write-Host ''

        $findInstallationType= (FindInstallationType $solutionName $matches[0])

        switch ($findInstallationType) {
              -1 { 
                    #Downgrade
                    if(DoDowngradeYesOrNo){
                        RetractWspPackage($global:retractingPackage)
                        DeployWspPackage $solutionPath $solutionName
                    }
                    else{
                        Write-Host 'WSP Package' $wspFile.name 'was skipped.' 
                    }
                }

              0 {           
                    #Up to date
                    #RetractWspPackage($global:retractingPackage)
                    Write-Host 'WSP Package' $wspFile.name 'is up-to-date. No action was taken.' 

                }

             1  { 
                    #Upgrade
                    RetractWspPackage($global:retractingPackage)
                    DeployWspPackage $solutionPath $solutionName
                }

             2  { 
                    #Fresh Install
                    DeployWspPackage $solutionPath $solutionName                

                }

        }

    }       
    else{
        Write-Host 'WSP Package' $wspFile.name 'does not follow the right naming convention. Please correct the issue and run the installation again.'
    }
}
Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Answer (score 2):

Three minutes is about normal full retract and redeploy but this actually varies greatly depending on the content being deployed/retracted.  For example, if your WSP has thousands of images then it will take longer both to retract and then to deploy than a WSP that only has a master page/JS file.

Comment: For multiserver farms, this process can also take longer as the action needs to run to completion on all servers before you can continue to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

There are two PowerShell cmdlets that can be useful in determining your situation: Trace-Command and Get-Counter.

Two posts that provide examples for the above are - [Low-level Tracing & Debugging](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2008/12/17/powershell-abcs---d-is-for-debugging.aspx) and [Monitoring system performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872428.aspx).